# Test platform for PSTN Call simulation

Tags: testing, simulator, phone-call, platform

I need a test platform which will make and answer PSTN calls, play some voice files and afterwards will disconnect call etc. Basically hardware may be standart dial-up modems or some special kind for this purpose.

Can you suggest such platforms, preferably open source?

Answer (score 0):

I've used pyserial for this type of thing before: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/

There's also a TCP/IP serial bridge that simplifies things a lot and I found really quite useful: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#tcp-ip-serial-bridge

I used it in conjunction with the built in modem on my laptop. It was a bit tricky to configure, but it worked in the end. It should work just fine with any standard dial-up modem.